# How to add a function to the body of smtp message and send it every 12 hours?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a script that check if a YouTube video still online and each 12 hours send an e-mail with the status for me.

I come up with 3 pieces of code, but now I'm having a hard time to "blend" them correctly. So, I'll try to explain the problems I'm facing:

Heres the first part of the code, it's doing the job well (thanks to @KetZoomer that helped me out):

```
import requests

def out_of_air():
    videos = {"id1": None, "id2": None, "id3": None, "id4": None}
    for i in videos:
        id_of_video = i
        your_api_key = 'myapi' 
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={}&key={}&part=status'.format(id_of_video, your_api_key)
        url_get = requests.get(url)
        pprint(url_get.json())
        videos[i] = url_get.json()

    for video in videos:
        if videos[video]["pageInfo"]["resultsPerPage"] == 0:
            print(f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video} is offline")
        else:
            print(f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video} is online")
```

Then I want the `print` part to be embed in an email, so I tried this hoping that what I see in my screen ended up in the email:

```
import smtplib
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login('MYADDRESS', 'PASSWORD')
    
    subject = 'Online or not'
    body = out_of_air()
    msg = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'
    
    smtp.sendmail('MYADDRESS', 'OTHERADDRESS', msg)
```

I receive the e-mail, but the body come as "none", when I wanted the printed results.

Besides that, I could not put the email code inside of another function to run the code below:

```
import schedule
import time

schedule.every(12).hours.do(send_email)


while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You need to `return` a value from `out_of_air()` in order for it to end up in `body`. You also have an indentation error in `out_of_air()` in the `for i in videos:` loop.

Comment: Is it the case that you want everything that you print in `out_of_air()` to end up in the email body?

Comment: @MichaelRuth Thanks, the indentation was wrong only in the post. I edited. I don't want everything in the email body, just the print result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return, from `out_of_air()`, the value you want to put in the email body. This should be done with a buffer since you're `print`ing within a loop.

```py
from io import StringIO
import requests

def out_of_air():
    videos = {"id1": None, "id2": None, "id3": None, "id4": None}
    buf = StringIO()
    for i in videos:
        id_of_video = i
        your_api_key = 'myapi' 
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={}&key={}&part=status'.format(id_of_video, your_api_key)
        url_get = requests.get(url)
        pprint(url_get.json())
        videos[i] = url_get.json()

    for video in videos:
        if videos[video]["pageInfo"]["resultsPerPage"] == 0:
            buf.write(f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video} is offline\n")
        else:
            buf.write(f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video} is online\n")
    
    buf.seek(0)
    return buf.read()
```

Comment: When I ran ```out_of_air()``` I get something like this ```<_io.StringIO at 0x7fcd64c6cdc0>```

Comment: Updated function to return a `str` instead of `io.StringIO`

Comment: Tks, Michael! It worked. Now I need to figure out how to run these two pieces of code each 12 hours. I'm doing some research and testing… Any tips? :)

Comment: `Cron` is the simplest way on a Linux/Unix machine, but there can be issues with collision. I don't think collision will be a problem in this case.